# MySQL - Joins and Between

Tags: mysql, sql, join, between

> List all the actors who made a film during the 1950s and also in the 1980s.

When I try exclusively:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM movies AS m
JOIN castings AS c
JOIN actors AS a
ON m.id = c.movieid
AND c.actorid = a.id
WHERE (m.yr BETWEEN 1950 AND 1959)
```

or:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM movies AS m
JOIN castings AS c
JOIN actors AS a
ON m.id = c.movieid
AND c.actorid = a.id
WHERE (m.yr BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989)
```

I get results for both separate queries. However I get no rows when I combine these.

```
SELECT a.name
FROM movies AS m1
JOIN movies AS m2
JOIN castings AS c
JOIN actors AS a
ON m1.id = c.movieid
AND m2.id = c.movieid
AND c.actorid = a.id
AND m1.id < m2.id
WHERE (m1.yr BETWEEN 1950 AND 1959) AND (m2.yr BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989);
```

How can I find the names I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your existing query, a straight-forward approach is to use aggregation, and filter with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM movies AS m
JOIN castings AS c ON m.id = c.movieid
JOIN actors AS a ON c.actorid = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
HAVING 
    MAX(m.yr BETWEEN 1950 AND 1959) = 1 
    AND MAX(m.yr BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in where clause.

```
SELECT 
    a.name 
FROM
    actors AS a 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 
        1 
    FROM
        movies m,
        castings c 
    WHERE c.actorid = a.id 
        AND m.id = c.movieid 
        AND (m.yr BETWEEN 1950 
            AND 1959) 
    LIMIT 1) 
    OR EXISTS
    (SELECT 
        1 
    FROM
        movies m,
        castings c 
    WHERE c.actorid = a.id 
        AND m.id = c.movieid 
        AND (m.yr BETWEEN 1980 
            AND 1989) 
    LIMIT 1)
```

Or you can use Group By like the following while getting number of movies:

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    SUM(IF(m.yr BETWEEN 1950 AND 1959, 1, 0)) AS e1950,     -- Number of Movies in 1950s
    SUM(IF(m.yr BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989, 1, 0)) AS e1980      -- Number of Movies in 1980s
FROM movies AS m
JOIN castings AS c
JOIN actors AS a
ON m.id = c.movieid
AND c.actorid = a.id
GROUP BY a.name HAVING e1950 > 0 AND e1980 > 0;
```